# How to add Nuget to visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, nuget, nuget-package, signalr.client

I installed a telekit template for web chatting, it messed up my nuget package folder destination, so I lost the ability to add current/future nuget to my visual studio solutions.
So I reinstalled visual studio 2019.
Now am trying to add a Nuget package "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" to my visual studio. Any advice?

Comment: First, please try to delete the file under %APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\NuGet.config, restart VS , [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all files . Then, try to install that package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to add Nuget to visual studio

You can first do these operations to clean your environemnt:

**1)** close VS, delete the global `nuget.config` under  `%APPDATA%\Roaming\.nuget\`

**2)** restart VS, [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete all nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user account)\.nuget\packages`

Then, open your asp.net project in VS IDE and right-click on it and select **Manage Nuget Packages**

And you can follow mys steps by the below picture and note to select the `nuget.org` nuget package source.

[image]

Then you will install such package in your project.

**Besides**, if you face any error when you install nuget packages, you can describe the issue in detailed so that we can troubleshoot the issue more qucikly.